# Using PHP $_POST to remember a option in a select box?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form which POSTs to itselft so the user can do things that you would find in a Shopping Cart.

e.g. Increase quantity, select postage type.

My problem is for my form Select element called "postage" whenever the form reloads itself , it forgets what was selected.

All my other fields remember their values using this:

```
<input type="text" name="postcode" value="<?php echo $_POST['postcode']; ?> " />
```

How do I use the $_POST value to automatically select the option in the select field that was done by the user?

I tried this:

```
<select name="postage" selected="<?php echo $_POST['postage']; ?>" >
```

and this

```
<select name="postage" value="<?php echo $_POST['postage']; ?>" >
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You almost got it. You need to set the attribute `selected="selected"` (the exact form you need technically depends on your HTML doctype, but this is a safe default) on the `<option>` element if and only if the value of `$postage` equals the value of the element. So:

```
<select name="postage">
<option value="foo" 
    <?php if ($_POST['postage'] == "foo") echo 'selected="selected" '; ?>
 >
</select>
```

Note that this violates the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) because you now have two occurrences of the string `"foo"` in there, so it's a prime candidate for refactoring. A good approach would be to keep value/text pairs in an array and iterate over it with `foreach` to produce the `<option>` tags.

Comment: Thanks, I am using HTML5. However I am going to take your advice on staying with the safe defaults on HTML for compatbility :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to foreach through all the options.

Make an array with all the dropdown options, loop through that, and compare with what is stored in post.

E.G.:

```
<?php
$aDropd = array("apple","orange","banana");
echo "<select>";
foreach($aDropd as $sOption){
  $sSel = ($sOption == $_POST['postage'])? "Selected='selected'":"";
  echo "<option   $sSel>$sOption</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score 1):

no its not working at all..you need to put some kind of loop for that.

```
For Example : foreach($record => $values){
                   if($values == $_POST['postage']){
                       $selected = "selected='selected' ";
                      }else{
                       $selected = "";
                      }
             }

<input name="postage" value="1" <?=$selected?> >
```

**EDITED:**

```
                      if($_POST['postage'] == 1){
                           $selected1 = "selected='selected' ";
                          }else if($_POST['postage'] == 2){
                           $selected2 = "selected='selected' ";
                          } and so on..........



    <select name="postage">
     <option value="1" <?=$selected1;?> />
     <option value="2" <?=$selected2;?> />
    </select>
```

I think this may be helpful to you..you can ask me if anything else needed...

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks however this wont work for my design, as my option values are in a seperate file which I include into my page

Comment: its still working good.. you just need to check all the values manually without looping..simple. :) See edited answer..

Answer (score 0):

The value of selected should be selected

```
<select name="postage" value="1" <?php echo (($_POST['postage'] == 1)?'selected="selected"':''); ?> >
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html syntax is wrong. The correct way to write the html is like this:

```
<select>
<option value ="<?php echo $_POST['postage']; ?>" selected="selected"></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make it shorter:

```
<select>
<option value ="<?=$_POST['postage']; ?>" selected="selected"></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<select name="foo">
<option value="1" <?php echo strcmp($_POST['foo'],"1")==0?"selected=\"selected\"":"" ?>>option1</option>
<option value="2" <?php echo strcmp($_POST['foo'],"2")==0?"selected=\"selected\"":"" ?>>option2</option>
```